# Terraform - file provisioner doesn't copy files into place with azurerm

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm trying to populate files on a Ubuntu 16.04 server created in Azure using Terraform v0.9.3 using the file provisioner from OSX Sierra. No file tests work, even when I try to copy into publicly writable directories (/var/tmp, /tmp). Is this another "works in AWS but doesn't work with azurerm features? Nothing from google.

## Terraform snippet

```
#copy app file into place:
 provisioner "file" {
    source      = "/Users/person/Terraform/Azure/files/busybox.sh"
    destination = "/var/tmp/busybox.sh"
  }
#can I copy as root?:
 provisioner "file" {
    source      = "/Users/person/Terraform/Azure/files/random_file"
    destination = "/root/QWERTYFILE"
  }
#can I copy anywhere?:
 provisioner "file" {
    source      = "/Users/person/Coding/Azure/files/random_file"
    destination = "/tmp/"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the connection session as below? Let me know if it works or not

```
# Copies the file as the root user using SSH
provisioner "file" {
  source      = "conf/myapp.conf"
  destination = "/etc/myapp.conf"

  connection {
    type     = "ssh"
    user     = "root"
    password = "${var.root_password}"
  }
}
```

You can set `private_key` if you don't want to use a password.

> private_key - The contents of an SSH key to use for the connection. These can be loaded from a file on disk using the file() interpolation function. This takes preference over the password if provided.

```
private_key = "${file("${path.module}/my-private-key")}"
```

Refer:

[Provisioner Connections](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html)

Comment: I hadn't tried that, thanks. Getting the same error as before:


    azurerm_virtual_machine.deploy01_vm: Still creating... (9m0s elapsed)
    Error applying plan:

    1 error(s) occurred:

    * azurerm_virtual_machine.deploy01_vm: 1 error(s) occurred:

    * dial tcp :22: getsockopt: connection refused

Comment: did you open the firewall( security groups) for port 22?

Comment: @perniciouscaffeine Do you use `root` or other user? You could not login root with password in Azure.

Comment: This is set to login as a non-root user with a valid password. 
Code below:   
  provisioner "file" {
     source      = "/var/jenkins_home/QWERTYFILE"
     destination = "/var/tmp/QWERTYFILE"

     connection {
     type     = "ssh" 
     user     = "deployroot"
     password = "the_password"
      }
   }

Comment: I don't think that's a password problem. The new error is `connection refused`, so please check if you open the firewall (port 22) or not.

Comment: @perniciouscaffeine Do you associate NSG to your VM, if yes, you should open port 22 on it.

Comment: Port 22 is open and I can SSH in during the time I'm getting the Connection Refused, which is why this is so confusing.